# Knockout css data-bind doesn't apply class

Tags: css, knockout.js

So I'm having a very, very strange issue, so here's a code snippet where the problem is happening:

`<td class="editable ageCell" data-source="Age" data-bind="css: {'modified': true}"></td>`

Basically what is going wrong is that it does not add the modified class. At all. Strangely, when I added a text binding, like `modified:true, text: 'testatest'`, it does apply it.

What is going on? I'm not even close to a web developer expert, but I even asked my two senior project leads and they can't figure it out.

Comment: Provide a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Are you sure the class is not applied? It won't show in the markup, maybe it is applied but you don't see the difference because the class does not add anything visible. Try setting a big font size for example in the `modified` class, just to check (`font-size: 48px !important;`)

Comment: I have inspected it, that's how I know that it isn't being added. I will try the text thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that in some framework that was being used, there was a function that served no purpose but to remove classes from cells when it was called, and it was being called right after my modified adder, so that wraps up this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your web page in browser console and check the class `modified` present or not.
If it is there, then probably the problem is with your text content inside the td element. it may be null or empty. Also make sure that there is no script error in browser console.

Try and understand this:

### HTML

```
<div class="editable ageCell" data-source="Age" data-bind="css: {'modified': false}, text:text"></div>

<div class="editable ageCell" data-source="Age" data-bind="css: {'modified': true}, text:text"></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var model = function()
{
    var self=this;
    self.modified = ko.observable(false);
    self.text = ko.observable('Sample Text');
        
};

ko.applyBindings(new model());
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5LRGU/)**

Comment: While this works, unfortunately it does not exactly jive with my data model, as data-source="Age" indicates that it is getting the age from a controller which gets it from a model or something along those lines, I've just recently been assigned to fix this tool structure, and I'm not 100% certain how it gets passed, but I am pretty sure that Age is contextually linked to a deeper level of the code where it is retrieved from a database, which AFAIK, the javascripts do not have access to, this being a pretty strong MVC structure, so it's not practical to have the text in the JS

Comment: I'm not talking about get the text from the js, check the browser consoles elements tab,
rendered html is displayed there in a tree structure,
then find the table cell, there you can check the `modified` class is present or not also the text is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

There's another reason why a class might not be applied I ran into: It gets overridden by a subsequent css-declaration:

```
<td class="editable ageCell" data-source="Age" data-bind="css: {'modified': true}, css: unrelatedcssclass"></td>
```

In this case 'modified' will never appear, but 'unrelatedcssclass' will.
To fix that, merge both declarations to

```
<td class="editable ageCell" data-source="Age" data-bind="css: {'modified': true, 'unrelatedcssclass' : true}"></td>
```